# Apt-get error when upgrading mysql from running out of room

Tags: apt, ubuntu-12.04, mysql5.5

I ran out of room on my drive on an ec2 instance and it mounted the overflow /tmp space. I noticed this when I did an apt-get update/upgrade and the upgrade failed because it had no more room on tmp. I fixed the space issue now when I try and upgrade again I get:

> You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
>   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    mysql-server-5.5 : Depends: mysql-server-core-5.5 (= 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 is installed
>   E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

So I tried apt-get -f install and get this error:

> dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server-5.5:
>    mysql-server-5.5 depends on mysql-server-core-5.5 (= 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.1); however:
>     Version of mysql-server-core-5.5 on system is 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.2.
>   dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
>    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
>   No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
>                                                                                                             dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
>    mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
>     Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.
>   dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
>    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
>   No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
>                                                                                                             Errors were encountered while processing:
>    mysql-server-5.5
>    mysql-server
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I tried to use apt-get clean but it did not work. I am hoping there is an easier fix than try to remove/purge mysql because I have databases I use every day.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're stuck because of a too new version of mysql-server-core-5.5  (5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 vs. 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) for your mysql-server-5.5 package.

Try to install the latest mysql-server-5.5 package:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install mysql-server-5.5
```

If this won't work, it's also safe to remove the mysql-server package via

```
apt-get remove mysql-server-5.5
```

and installing it again. As long as you don't use the `purge` option, your databases won't get deleted. If apt-get is trying to remove too many dependencies as well, there's also the way to remove the package directly via dpkg without dependencies:

```
dpkg -r --force-depends mysql-server-5.5
```

If you are still afraid of losing your databases, just backup them somewhere before, e.g.

```
 cp -arv /var/lib/mysql /root
```

Comment: dpkg -r --force-depends mysql-server-5.5 worked and then I did apt-get install mysql-server-5.5 Thanks